# Yii2 ActiveDataProvider does not return actual data in REST API

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I am developing a REST API using Yii2.
In most of my controller actions, after creating the proper query, at the end I usually do:

```
return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query
    ]);
```

and I get the actual data in the REST call.
But recently in one of my controller when I use the above code I get the ActiveDataProvider object itself (the query, key, db ...)

I know I can use

```
return $dataProvider->getModels();
```

but what is causing this? why is it working in other controllers?

**EDIT**

I found out something: when I add the afterAction() to the controller, this happens. even when I do not change the $result:

```
public function afterAction($action, $result) {
    parent::afterAction($action, $result);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: update your question and add  sample code for your two different controller/action (the one that not work correctly and one that work right) please

Comment: First check your config for any response settings and the controller for an afterAction().